# TeXLive tlmgr on HiDPI screens?

Tags: texlive, installing

I have recently installed TeXlive on a new Linux system with `install-tl` and then I used `tlmgr` to tweak the installation.  However, on my HiDPI screen with resolution 2560x1440 the fonts in tlmgr are almost unreadably small.  I know I can use a console/curses based tlmgr, but it would be nice to use the perl/tk app.  How can the font be improved on my screen?  Is there a version which uses a more modern toolkit than Tk?

Comment: The command line version is the default and recommended for GNU/Linux systems. It is also more complete than the GUI, as I understand it. (I've never seen the GUI, so I'm just going by the docs I've read.) Which is to say, I'm sure there is nothing based on another toolkit and I doubt there is very likely to be as I suspect this is not exactly a priority on these systems. (Whereas the GUI is more of a priority on Windows, of course, and OS X.)

Comment: I asked on the texlive-list if fonts can be enlarged and Norbert answered "Not by now. I will look into it whether I can find a simple way around it till freeze time. (Perl/Tk is not very good in that)".

Answer (score 4):

I have adjusted tlmgr/tlmgrgui perl scripts so that standard arguments for font selection will work - this will be included in tomorrow's (20160517) tlpretest for TL2016. With this, a simple

```
tlmgr --font 'Helvetica 24' gui
```

will give you a much bigger font than usual.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was fast ;-). And even if I don't use the gui very often, I like large fonts. I will test it tomorrow on windows.

Comment: Many thanks indeed!  I didn't expect a result from a developer so fast!

Comment: Your welcome. I normally try to fix things, but someone need to point me to the problems, thanks Ulrike!

Comment: I tried on windows. Single quotes didn't work (I got an ` unknown action: 24'` message), but double quotes where ok: `tlmgr --font "Helvetica 24" gui` worked (the effect is quite dramatic on my monitor, 14 is a better value).  Only the menu titles remain small.

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting. Need to try it on Windows, too. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 15.10 system, I can influence font choice with global X resources. Line in ~.Xresources, e.g.:

```
*Font: -*-nimbus sans l-medium-r-normal-*-14-*-*-*-p-*-iso10646-1
```

The font name matches the one listed in the xfontsel utility. So, this is pretty prehistoric.

Activation of this new/changed line:

```
xrdb merge ~/.Xresources
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Fedora 27 system with TeXLive 2017, which is installed on a MacBook Pro Retina 13 inch best results are achieved with

```
tlmgr --font 'Helvetica 12' gui
```

Strange enough without the font declaration you will get the above mentioned behavior.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!